# Calling a method correctly: (Java)

Tags: java

> Create a method named getNextProjectIndex() that returns an int that
>   gets the next index of the projects array that contains a -1.0. Find
>   the next item in the projects array that contains a -1.0 and return
>   that index of the array. This method should return -1 if the array is
>   full. -1 is a common flag to indicate failure in methods that should
>   only return non-negative integers.

I am having trouble calling this method in my main method. Does the problem lie in my getNextProjectIndex method or my main method in how I am calling it?

```
  public double getNextProjectIndex()
  {
    int i = 0;
    int full = -1;
    while(i < projects.length)
    {
      if (projects[i] == -1)
      {

        return i;
      }
      else if (i == (projects.length - 1) && projects[i] != -1)
      {
        return full;
      }

    }

    return i;

  }
```

Here is my main method:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String [ ] args)
  {
    Student testStudent = new Student("BL", "Hill", 34);
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println(testStudent.getFname() + " " + testStudent.getLname() );

    while(i < 5)
    {
      if(testStudent.getNextProjectIndex() != 0)
      {      
        testStudent.setProjectScore(10.0, i);
        System.out.println("Scores are: "+ testStudent.getProjectScore(i));
      }  


      i++;
    }


  }

}
```

When the program is run only one score is displayed rather than 5 scores. It does not completely run through the loop. Only -1 should be returned from that method if ALL slots in the array are filled.

Comment: So what "trouble" are you having?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the issue that you are seeing?

Comment: I am seeing this homework assignment for at least the 10th time in 2 years. You must have a horrible lecturer.

Comment: When the program is run only one score is displayed rather than 5 scores. It does not completely run through the loop. Only -1 should be returned from that method if ALL slots in the array are filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that your program hangs. In the `while` loop in `getNextProjectIndex()`, `i` is never incremented, thus causing an infinite loop.

--Edit--
Also, you have some cruft in the method try:

```
public int getNextProjectIndex()
{
  int i = 0;
  while(i < projects.length) {
    if (projects[i] == -1)
      return i;
    ++i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

--Edit-- changed to `while` loop, since that's apparently required.

Comment: That seemed to fix the issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

> Create a method named getNextProjectIndex() **that returns an int**

You have declared your method as returning a double, even though the spec says to return an int, and you are attempting to return an int `i` in the function:

```
public double getNextProjectIndex()
       ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that you are incrementing the while loop in the getNextProjectIndex.